# JSON Schema if/then/else conditional behaving strangely

Tags: json, yaml, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm seeing some weird behavior with my JSON schema, can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. In plain english the behavior I want is "if `useColumnForKey` is true, `key` must also be true.

Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fields": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/field"
      },
      "contains": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "const": true
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "key"
        ]
      },
      "minItems": 1
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "name",
    "fields"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "field": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "description": "The field name",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
          "description": "The field description",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "key": {
          "description": "Whether or not this field is the primary key or part of the composite primary key for the model",
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "useColumnNameForKey": {
          "description": "Whether or not to use the exact column name as part of the key. If false, the global version of the column will be used. If this property is preset the key property must be true.",
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "useColumnNameForKey": {
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "const": true
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "key"
        ]
      },
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "name",
        "description"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

YAML file this runs against (with comments indication what's what):

```yaml
name: SomeThing
fields:

# No errors here, as you'd expect
  - name: field1
    description: description1
    key: true

# Error: missing property "key". What the heck, why?
  - name: field2
    description: description2.

# Error: missing property "key". This is the intended functionality.
  - name: field3
    description: description3.
    useColumnNameForKey: true

# Error: Property "key" must have value "true". This is the intended functionality.
  - name: field4
    description: description4.
    key: false
    useColumnNameForKey: true

# No errors here, also as expected.
  - name: field5
    description: description5.
    # key: true
    useColumnNameForKey: false
```

What I think is happening is the `"if"` condition is being evaluated to `true` when it shouldn't be... I just don't know why! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out right after posting. Rubber duck, I guess.

Turns out you also need to define `"required":[...]` for whatever property you're making the conditional about, too. Excerpt:

```
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "useColumnNameForKey": {
                "const": true
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "useColumnNameForKey" // Here's what I was missing!
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "key": {
                "const": true
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "key"
            ]
          }
        }
```

Comment: The value of `if` is a subschema. The subschema when applied to the instance location must validate if you want the `then` subschema to be applied.